# Sharing Gems between Chef and System Ruby

Tags: chef, security

I know about the `chef_gem` resource obv, but in the interests of good system hygiene I would like to avoid as much as possible duplication, so I would like to share Gems between the embedded Ruby within Chef, and the system-wide one. Additionally I have become aware of a troubling situation: the Gems I have in the system Ruby come from the known-good local Yum repo and are installed via RPM over the LAN whereas `chef_gem` goes off to the public Internet, and [recent events in the Python community](http://www.nbu.gov.sk/skcsirt-sa-20170909-pypi/) have made me very concerned about this. I have tried setting `ENV['GEM_PATH']` in my recipe both before and inside a `ruby_block` but this appears to have no effect, I get a failure on `require`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take your points one by one:

> but in the interests of good system hygiene I would like to avoid as much as possible duplication

Can you ensure your system ruby will evolve at the same pace as the Chef's ruby ? Main point of chef coming as a bundle with its own ruby comes back from Chef 10 which was installed via a simple gem command and was usually a problem switching between ruby needed for applications and ruby needed by chef, the same goes for gem dependencies. I would advise against mixing system and chef ruby.

> the Gems I have in the system Ruby come from the known-good local Yum repo and are installed via RPM over the LAN whereas chef_gem goes off to the public Internet

While I understand and agree with the worrying about recent pipy events, there's two things here:

- Your system ruby install gems from yum repository because your system ruby's `gem` command has been tweaked for that, that's specific to your distribution. -
- Chef's ruby use usual ruby method going to rubygems.org, as any ruby installed by rbenv or any other way than yum install would do.

If you really want to use a local repo you'll have to [set up a gem server](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/) (alternatively, some artifact repositories can handle that also) and set-up the sources for gem using chef's [`gem sources`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-sources) in `/opt/chef/embedded/bin`.

If you're using a chef client above 13.0 your can use the `rubygems_url` in client.rb to tweak that:

> ```
> rubygems_url
> ```
>
> The location to source rubygems. It can be set to a string or array of
>   strings for URIs to set as rubygems sources. This allows individuals
>   to setup an internal mirror of rubygems for “airgapped” environments.
>   Default value: https://www.rubygems.org.
>   Changed in Chef Client 13.0.

And finally:

> I have tried setting ENV['GEM_PATH'] in my recipe both before and
>   inside a ruby_block but this appears to have no effect, I get a
>   failure on require

Chef omnibus package hardcode some values specially to avoid interfering with the system ruby, I think the GEM_PATH environment variable is ignored when searching for gem you `require` within the recipe code. I don't think there's a workaround for this, and again you're heading to a compatibility problem on mid term as you'll have a drift between chef's ruby and system ruby.